# Horizontal Scrolling in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Pro Informant -app has this kind of scrolling to left and right. How can you do this in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) is probably what you're looking for.